# RHEL8 の環境で、ファイルが存在するのに実行すると "No such file or directory" エラーが表示される

Tags: linux, rhel

Amazon EC2 上の RHEL8 (x86_64) にて、とあるプログラム (バイナリファイル) が確実にファイルシステム上に存在するにも関わらず、実行しようとすると "No such file or directory" エラーで実行できません。

`ldd` コマンドで共有ライブラリもチェックしてみましたが、こちらは問題無さそうです。

**実行環境:**

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)
```

**実際のエラーやファイルの情報等:**

```
$ ./lmutil -v
-bash: ./lmutil: No such file or directory

$ ls -l lmutil
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1219896 Dec 21  2021 lmutil*

$ file lmutil
lmutil: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped

$ ldd lmutil
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffeaf9fe000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2a7da7d000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2a7d6fb000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2a7d4e3000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2a7d11e000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2a7cf1a000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f2a7cd12000)
        /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2a7dc9d000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"RHEL8 No such file or directory" をキーワードに Google 検索したところ、以下のページがヒットしました。

[No such file or directory? But the file exists! - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/133389)

主なやり取りは Ubuntu での話がメインですが、[回答の一つ](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035037) のコメント欄でちょうど自分が実行しようとしている `lmutil` についての話が出ており、"lsb" というキーワードで rpm パッケージを検索したところ、以下の通りいくつかヒットしました。

```
$ sudo dnf search lsb
Last metadata expiration check: 0:44:21 ago on Wed 14 Sep 2022 05:54:35 AM UTC.
================================================================ Name & Summary Matched: lsb ================================================================
redhat-lsb-core.x86_64 : LSB Core module support
redhat-lsb-core.i686 : LSB Core module support
redhat-lsb-cxx.x86_64 : LSB CXX module support
redhat-lsb-cxx.i686 : LSB CXX module support
redhat-lsb-desktop.i686 : LSB Desktop module support
redhat-lsb-desktop.x86_64 : LSB Desktop module support
redhat-lsb-languages.i686 : LSB Languages module support
redhat-lsb-languages.x86_64 : LSB Languages module support
redhat-lsb-printing.i686 : LSB Printing module support
redhat-lsb-printing.x86_64 : LSB Printing module support
redhat-lsb-submod-multimedia.x86_64 : LSB Multimedia submodule support
redhat-lsb-submod-multimedia.i686 : LSB Multimedia submodule support
redhat-lsb-submod-security.x86_64 : LSB Security submodule support
redhat-lsb-submod-security.i686 : LSB Security submodule support
===================================================================== Name Matched: lsb =====================================================================
redhat-lsb.x86_64 : Implementation of Linux Standard Base specification
```

今回はこの中の `redhat-lsb-core` パッケージをインストールすることで解決しました。

**パッケージをインストール:**

```
$ sudo dnf install redhat-lsb-core
```

**パッケージ追加後の実行結果:** (正常に実行できるようになった)

```
$ ./lmutil -v
Copyright (c) 1989-2020 Flexera. All Rights Reserved.
lmutil v11.17.1.0 build 268393 x64_lsb
```